# Tracking keywords on Twitter via Streaming

Tags: unix, shell, twitter

I am tracking some keywords on Twitter using the command below, I want to print just the "screen_name" property of the tweet author, could get the command above working but want remove "quotes" from author screen_name, how could I do this?

curl -N -d @tracking http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -umyuser:mypass | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^screen_name/ {print $2}'

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove quotes with SED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248905/remove-quotes-with-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression parsing of JSON is always a bad idea. Parse the markup into an object with a full JSON parser, then pick out the field you are interested in.