# Remove quotes with SED

Tags: unix, shell

I am tracking some keywords on Twitter using the command below. I want to print just the "screen_name" property of the tweet author.  I could get the command below working but want to remove "quotes" from the author screen_name.  How could I do this?

```
curl -N -d @tracking http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json \
     -umyuser:mypass | \
sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | \
awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^screen_name/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra single quotes here? `sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g'` Shouldn't it just be `sed -e 's/[{}]//g'`? What does the output of the `curl` command look like before it goes to `sed` and `awk`. Pipelines that include both `sed` and `awk` can often be simplified into ones without `sed`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Why use sed?

```
| tr -d '"'
```

Right tool for the right job.

Comment: my script need to be compatible solaris :-) so i need a sed because tr is not great on solaris

Comment: There's nothing majorly wrong with `tr` on solaris as long as you use `/usr/xpg6/bin/tr` and not `/usr/bin/tr`.

Comment: Not sure the logical thing to do in an agentless configuration system is to go look for binaries in xpg6 on your target. I'll keep that in mind, but i rather make a script going around by using sed.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I recommend just setting `PATH` to `/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`; this should use the best available version of Unix tools on Solaris and Linux without requiring any custom find-the-binary code.

Comment: And, if you want to filter out/remove a single quote, here it is:  | tr -d "'"

Comment: @Plasmmer: You could also use \ in either case: `| tr -d \"` or `| tr -d \'`  -- you just have to pass the character literally to tr.

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
...existing_commands | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: If your current command give `"user_name"` as output then adding `| sed 's/"//g'` at the end should give `user_name` as output.

Comment: no not work.. and if i execute my initial command with " > file" at the end it does not write in the file. Maybe something related to the {print $2}. Thoughts?

Comment: @user430830: if the 'sed' command given is not working, then there is a problem further back in the pipeline of commands.  You might find it beneficial to insert '`tee fileN.out |`' (for various different values of N) between the various stages of the pipeline to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, this this utility sounds like it can be useful for parsing the json twitter returns: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

```
cat a.txt | tr -d "\042"
```

It is better because it works in Windows too (using gnuwin32)

Comment: Sed also works under gnuwin32.