# Escape "./" when using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I wanted to use grep to exclude words from $lastblock by using a pipeline, but I found that grep works only for files, not for stdout output.

So, here is what I'm using:

```sh
lastblock="./2.json"
echo $lastblock | sed '1,/firstmatch/d;/.json/,$d'
```

I want to exclude `./` and `.json`, keeping only what is between.
This sed command is correct for this purpose, but how to escape the `./` replacing `firstmatch` so it can work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!

Just discovered today the `tr` command thanks to [this legendary, unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249363/5623661).

When searching all over Google for how to exclude "." and "/", 100% of StackOverflow answers didn't helped.

So, to escape characters from the output of a command, just append this pipe:

`| tr -d "{character-emoji-anything-you-want-to-exclude}"`

So, a full working and simple sample:

`echo "./2.json" | tr -d "/" | tr -d "." | tr -d "json"`

And done!

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's [Parameter Substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```sh
lastblock="./2.json"
name="${lastblock##*/}" # strips from the beginning until last / -> 2.json
base="${name%.*}"       # strips from the last . to the end      -> 2
```

Comment: Technically speaking that [P.E.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) is not bash only, it is also defined/required by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

> but I found that grep works only for files, not for stdout output.

here it is. (if your grep supports the `-P` flag.

```
lastblock="./2.json"
echo "$lastblock" | grep -Po '(?<=\./).*(?=\.)'
```

---

> but how to escape the ./

With `sed`(1), escape it using a back slash `\`

```
lastblock="./2.json"
echo "$lastblock" | sed 's/^\.\///;s/\..*$//'
```

Or use a different delimiter like a pipe `|`

```
sed 's|^\./||;s|\..*$||'
```

---

with `awk`

```
lastblock="./2.json"
echo "$lastblock" | awk -F'[./]+' '{print $2}'
```

---

Starting from `bashv3`, regular expression pattern matching is supported using the `=~` operator inside the `[[ ... ]]` keyword.

```
lastblock="./2.json"
regex='^\./([[:digit:]]+)\.json'
[[ $lastblock =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

---

Although a [P.E.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) should suffice just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to use grep to exclude words from $lastblock by using a pipeline, but I found that grep works only for files, not for stdout output.

Nonsense.  grep works the same for the same input, regardless of whether it is from a file or from the standard input.

> So, here is what I'm using:
>
> ```
> lastblock="./2.json"
> echo $lastblock | sed '1,/firstmatch/d;/.json/,$d'
> ```
>
> I want to exclude ./ and .json, keeping only what is between. This sed
> command is correct for this purpose,

That sed command is nowhere near correct for the stated purpose.  It has this effect:

- delete every *line* from the very first one up to and including the next subsequent one that matches the regular expression `/firstmatch/`, AND
- delete every *line* from the first one matching the regular expression `/.json/` to the last one of the file (and note that `.` is a regex metacharacter).

To remove part of a line instead of deleting a whole line, use an `s///` command instead of a `d` command.  As for escaping, you can escape a character to sed by preceding it with a backslash (`\`), which itself must be quoted or escaped to protect it from interpretation by the shell.  Additionally, most regex metacharacters lose their special significance when they appear inside a character class, which I find to be a more legible way to include them in a pattern as literals.  For example:

```
lastblock="./2.json"
echo "$lastblock" | sed 's/^[.]\///; s/[.]json$//'
```

That says to remove the literal characters `./` appearing at the beginning of the (any) line, and, separately, to remove the literal characters `.json` appearing at the end of the line.

Alternatively, if you want to modify only those lines that **both** start with `./` and end with `.json` then you can use a single `s` command with a capturing group and a backreference:

```
lastblock="./2.json"
echo "$lastblock" | sed 's/^[.]\/\(.*\)[.]json$/\1/'
```

That says that on lines that start with `./` and end with `.json`, capture everything between those two and replace the whole line with the captured part alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another character like '#' when you want to avoid slashes.
You can remember a part that matches and use it in the replacement.
Use `[.]` avoiding the dot to be any character.

```
echo "$lastblock" | sed -r 's#[.]/(.*)[.]json#\1#'
```